# Windows docker build warning non-windows docker host

Tags: windows, docker, jenkins

I am trying to build a docker image from a docker client (Windows) running this command:

```
docker --host a.b.c.d build --no-cache=true --build-arg CONFIGURATION=live -t imagename .
```

The docker host is also a Windows Docker but I get this error:

> SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against
>   a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build
>   context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to
>   double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and
>   directories.

And then this one after the first attempt:

> invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value

Anyone know why this happen? I had no error before, the only differences are in the code source. For information I am using Jenkins to build the project? Thanks.

**UPDATE 1 - Dockerfile**

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';"]

ARG CONFIGURATION
EXPOSE 80
ADD src/MyFolder/bin/$CONFIGURATION/ /ContainerFolder
CMD /ContainerFolder/MyApp.exe
```

Comment: Post your dockerfile. So you using Docker for Windows with WIndows container mode activated?

Comment: Yes all Windows. I've followed this link https://blog.docker.com/2016/09/build-your-first-docker-windows-server-container/ to set up Docker. Linux is not working with this install. Dockerfile added to the post.

Comment: From the looks of if it seems that your docker is in Linux container mode. You can test it by running `docker run alpine ls -alh /usr/bin` if this works in your script then probably your windows node is not in Windows container mode

Comment: I have found the problem (the docker run alpine was not working btw). By using wireshark I could see that the error was actually "This request is blocked by the Firewall Gateway Anti-Virus Service." I have allowed the request to pass and it worked.
Maybe the message was changed by the Docker Client because the gateway is linux based and it tried to interpret it. WIll never know.

Comment: Cool that its sorted. Thanks for sharing the findings

Answer (score 20):

From [thaJeztah on GitHub](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/20397#issuecomment-185471832):

> That warning was added, because the Windows filesystem does not have an option to mark a file as 'executable'. Building a linux image from a Windows machine would therefore break the image if a file has to be marked executable.
>
> For that reason, files are marked executable by default when building from a windows client; the warning is there so that you are notified of that, and (if needed), modify the Dockerfile to change/remove the executable bit afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed now. The problem was in the Gateway Firewall, it was detecting a file sent in the build context as a Trojan. Probably Docker build context zip file or use different extensions.

Comment: It's not fixed yet(_at least as of writing this comment_). Refer to [this screenshot](https://ctrlv.cz/7YMK) for clarification.

Comment: It has not fixed yet. Here is a [screenshot](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/8049878/96397440-22e81d00-11fc-11eb-8881-fe9ed359cd94.png).